# Obfuscation and jOOQ

Tags: java, obfuscation, jooq

I'm going to use jOOQ and I probably need obfuscation.

I don't know how jOOQ works under the hood.
Will the obfuscation process give issues to the application?

Comment: What are you going to obfuscate? Your database schema and the generated SQL? jOOQ? Or your own code? Or a combination thereof?

Comment: @Lukas I'm going to obfuscate the application; I will not obfuscate the database and the schema itself (do I understood correctly your question?) I will not obfuscate the libraries (jOOQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ uses reflection, internally:

1. to construct [custom POJO objects](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/)
2. to assign values from [Records to POJO objects](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into%28java.lang.Class%29) and [vice-versa](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from%28java.lang.Object%29)
3. to call Oracle ojdbc-specific methods without creating a dependency on ojdbc
4. to call Postgres JDBC-specific methods on PGobject types

In these areas, obfuscation may cause issues if you change method names

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It is much appreciated. So I will need to exclude the jOOQ generated code from the obfuscation process (I'm planning to use jOOQ code generation features). Is it correct? I hoped (just a little) that jOOQ generated code used string constants, so the obfuscation would be possible

Comment: I know it would be you the first to answer to my question :) I've tried jOOQ really fast and everything worked like a charm. I already love it :)

Comment: @Jako: Thanks for the feedback. I have a notification service on the jOOQ tag set up... :-) You can also obfuscate jOOQ-generated code. Just beware of the fact that jOOQ may no longer be able to map generated string constants (of corresponding database column names) to POJO getters and setters. One way to circumvent that is by generating POJOs with JPA annotations... Then, the method names no longer matter